Python For Loop variable assignment
I have 3 lists:
list_1, list_2, and list_3
I wish to loop through them via a For loop. But I want to use the list names as variables
So the For loop should be like -
for i in range(1,4):
   'list_' + i do something

I am unable to get the correct way to do this.
Can you please help?
Thank you

In a language like Python, the best way to do this is using a dictionary.
my_dict = {}
for i in range(1,4):
   my_dict['list_' + i] = "something"

Then you can access your values a variety of ways:
my_dict["list_1"]  # get a single value
my_dict.values()  # will return a list of the values

for var_name in my_dict: 
   my_dict[var_name]  # how you can get the value in a loop

